# Cannot load 64-bit SWT libraries on 32-bit JVM but I'm referencing the 32 bit library

Tags: java, x86, swt, 64-bit

As the title states I keep getting this error:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Cannot load 64-bit SWT libraries on 32-bit JVM
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.Library.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.Library.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.C.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
    at sosa.main.SOSAMain.<clinit>(SOSAMain.java:41)
Exception in thread "main"
```

The problem is I'm referencing the 32 bit swt.jar file in my build path but it is still giving me this error.

I've read all the other posts about needing the correct swt jar but the issue is this is a legacy project and I was given the code base with the included 32-bit swt jar file. But for some reason It doesn't seem to work on 32-bit JVM. It works fine on 64-bit JVM but the swt.jar is supposedly a 32-bit.

Has anyone ever had an issue like this?

Edit:

So apparantly no matter what swt jar file I put onto my build path it' still giving the same error, I tried a linux swt jar and the 32-bit swt jar. Could it be using the eclipse plug in swt jar file? If so is there anyway to not use this? I tried uninstalling all swt stuff but it doesn't seem possible to remove it? Or is there a way to specify not using it?

Comment: Did you verify that the jar is indeed 32bit?

Comment: Baz - Yes I have, could the issue be it's using the swt filee from the eclipse plug in? I don't understand where its referencing 64-bit libraries if only my 32-bit jar file in on the build path along with Jre6(x86).

Comment: So the Eclipse you are using is 64bit?

Comment: I was yes, but I just tried again on the 32-bit version I downloaded and get the same error.